# Opengl32.lib for Windows ARM64

Tags: windows, opengl, arm, static-libraries

I have a very specific case for this question. I am trying to port GZDoom to Windows-ARM64, but when I link, the OpenGL32.lib file is missing.

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opengl32.lib' [D:\gzdoom-arm\build\src\zdoom.vcxproj]`

Everything else compiles fine in the branch that I made for this project.

So I looked in the windows kit and sure enough, it is missing. However, in my copy of ARM64 windows, Opengl32.dll *is* indeed on the system, which means that the library is available to be used - likely for compatibility with i386-compiled projects, but that is not what I am trying to do here.

I am not asking where to find a copy of OpenGL32.lib. What I am more interested in, is whether any open source implementations of that specific library exist, and where can I find them. If it's in, let's say, Mesa3D - well, that's a massive project, so is there any specific part of that which I can compile that gives me just the .lib?

If that is not possible, then okay, let's say I drop the .lib entirely, exactly how would I go about resolving the library exports? How can I compile this project without removing OpenGL support entirely? (I know it's a bit of a gamble, but I am banking on OpenGL eventually becoming more mainstream with ARM64 windows, even if it is only for compatibility purposes)

My project for this can be found here: https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom/tree/arm64win

Comment: BTW, see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/announcing-the-opencl-and-opengl-compatibility-pack-for-windows-10-on-arm/)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this.
https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom/commit/5a0c84dd2d3e1798e7a99f4ec1696f678708f0e6

I cheated and bypassed opengl32.lib entirely. The necessary functions are now dynamically loaded directly. Even on x64 this still compiles and seems to work just fine.